# Catch Radio Button Click/Checked Event

Tags: .net, vb.net, radio-button

I can't browse what I need so, I might have asked.
How can I catch the rButtons checked change or click?
I have tried, `.Click, .CheckChanged` but the event does not fire.
What are the other options available?
[image]

```
Private Sub rbStop_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles rbStop.CheckedChanged
    zero()
End Sub

Private Sub rbStop_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles rbStop.Click
    zero()
End Sub
```

After choosing what type of timer, user must be able to set the time. But its not firing. Why is that?

Comment: pls give the code segment..

Comment: So when you debug, your events do not fire? What happens in the zero sub?

Comment: zero sub makes texts to zero and `readOnly = false`

Comment: Did you set a breakpoint and follow the code?

Comment: that's only one line. Why would I use breakpoint? I have encountered this thing in Java platform and I forgot what I did to catch it. ~ I tired breakpoint, it does go through the code, but still, does not fire.

Comment: If it goes thru the code - it is firing! That is the point.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @DonA.

```
Private Sub rbStop_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles rbStop.CheckedChanged
    zero()
End Sub
```

Worked for me. I've made wrong coding on the zero sub which is `.ReadOnly= True` that's why I thought it was not firing.